# Convergence in probability maximizing odds

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let's say you have this scenario: 
You are flipping a weighted coin that lands heads with probability $p$ $(p\lt \frac 12)$ and tails with probability $1-p$  $(1-p\gt \frac 12 (\text{obviously}))$. 
You start with an arbitrary score of $1000$ and can bet a part of your score $k$ where $k$ is less than your current score. If the coin lands on heads, $k$ is added to your score. If the coin lands on tails, $k$ is subtracted from your score.

The expected value of your score after every flip goes down; however, how should you bet your money if you want to maximize the chance of your score reaching $3000$?

My reasoning is that you should try to flip as few times as possible because the probability converges to *p* as we increase the amount of flips. A smaller amount of flips will give a higher divergence from *p*